# How to make the Visual Studio profiler show function calls properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

My Visual Studio (2012) does only show me the .exe and .dll files in the profiler. I searched the internet but I can not find a proper answer to my question. I asked my teachers aswell, but none seem to know the answer.

This is the only thing I see:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCmV7.png)

EDIT: I still can't seem to fix this, after +- 2 months. I tried some settings and my project settings have "Generate Debug Information" set to "Yes".

Comment: The error says you have no matching symbols. I assume you did not mess with the default settings so I assume your source code has been modified since your last build. Do a clean build.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I just rebuilt the entire solution, though, no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of Visual Studio 2012 (it has some symbol bug fixes). The problem you are seeing means we cannot decode the symbols, let me know if the update doesn't fix your issue